# How to quickly fill a buffer with a custom string?

Tags: c, algorithm

My requirement is to write a file with some given pattern (3 bytes of `char`). The file can be of any size, e.g. if the file size is 10 bytes, then the contents will be `"abcabcabca"` if the given pattern is `"abc"`.

Now, `memset` doesn't work for multiple characters. My question is:

> What is the quickest way to fill a buffer with such a string and then provide it to the write system call?

I can think of below steps

1. Open the file.
2. Fill the buffer (min 1024 chars if not specified) using a for loop and the write pattern.
3. Loop until size of file.

I am not sure how to achieve the filling of the buffer with a given pattern quickly.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about performance given the bottleneck will be file io.

Comment: In the time (or cost) it takes to read a buffer, you can assign to  the buffer contents a hundred times or more.

Comment: The most efficient solution is to write a 3-byte file and virtualize access to it so that any attempts to read it will implicitly return the correct bytes. Think outside the box!

Comment: Maybe you can use `memcpy` to repeatedly copy the pattern to the buffer. If you append the buffer's current content to itself this way, only log2(n) `memcpy`s are needed.

Comment: @Thomas If the file doesn't already exist, this whole exercise seems quite pointless to me. It does sound like the OP is trying to create something like a permanent file deletion program, ie a program that writes some rubbish pattern to a file 50 times or so, to delete any trace of the original data from the HD. To create a new file then rather sounds like "think outside the specification".

Comment: @Lundin Well if we're going to speculate: since when do homework assignments serve any practical purpose on their own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's algorithm is sound, just needs to implement it.

Any time spent writing the buffer, using a loop, `memcpy()`, etc. is swamped by the file I/O time.  So only modest optimization of the formation of the buffer is needed.

What this *really* is, is a fine opportunity to *profile* your code.  Try timing 2 implementations like the 2 below and see what time difference results.

```
int Fill_Basic(FILE *outf, size_t Length, char a, char b char c) {
  while (Length > 0) {
    if (Length > 0) {
      Length--;
      fputc(outf, a);
      }
    if (Length > 0) {
      Length--;
      fputc(outf, b);
      }
    if (Length > 0) {
      Length--;
      fputc(outf, c);
      }
    }
  return ferror(outf);
  }

int Fill_Faster(FILE *outf, size_t Length, char a, char b char c) {
  // A trick is to provide fwrite() with a "nice" buffer size.
  // This is often a power of 2 and is highly platform dependent, but a reasonable assertion.
  // Profiling would help access this.
  // Let's assume 1024
  size_t bsize = min(Length, 1024);
  char buf[bsize + 2];  // Allocate (3-1) extra.
  for (char *p = buf; p < &buf[bsize]; ) {
    *p++ = a;
    *p++ = b;
    *p++ = c;
    }
  // Optimization: each time through the loop, provide the buffer shifted as needed
  //  1st time "abcabc..."
  //  2nd time "bcabca..."
  //  3rd time "cabcab..."
  //  4th time "abcabc..."
  size_t Offset = 0;
  while (Length > 0) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<3; i++) {
      size_t t = min(Length, bsize);
      if (t != fwrite(&buffer[Offset], 1, t, outf)) handle_error();
      Length -= t;
      Offset += t;
      Offset %= 3;
      }
    }
  return ferror(outf);
  }
```

Comment: `for (size_t i=0; i<3; i++)` could be `for (int i=0; i<3; i++)`